# for loop for running a command for all files in a folder

Tags: shell-script, for

Suppose I have a folder which contains a lot of audio files. How can I write a for loop so that for each file `audioname.mp3` in the folder, these commads are run:

```
convert -size 300x200   xc:lightblue  -font Bookman-DemiItalic  -pointsize 40  -fill blue  -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 'audioname'" audioname.png
ffmpeg -i audioname.png -i audioname.mp3 audioname.flv
```

?

Comment: I'm frankly surprised that you couldn't use a find/xargs combination to prevent writing a bash loop.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus can you test with [my script here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9005360/). If it worked for you I will post it as an answer ;)

Comment: @KasiyA I test it, it partially works. some flvs are created and some are not with a few errors. btw, ffmpeg is no longer in Ubuntu repo you should compile its source code.

Comment: I think the problem is the the folder contents are changing.

Comment: no‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: @KasiyA: see this page: http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux

Comment: @KasiyA: you can replace `ffmpeg` with `avconv` instead.

Comment: Mandar Shinde's answer is almost correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
for file in ~/Main_dir/*.mp3; do
    convert -background lightblue -size 300x200 -fill blue  -pointsize 40 -gravity center label:"$(basename "$file" .mp3)" "${file%.*}.png";
    avconv -i "${file%.*}.png" -i "${file%.*}.mp3" "${file%.*}.flv";
done
```

for the discription of first [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) command see [my answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549163/draw-a-picture-from-command-line-in-ubuntu/549205#549205)

#### Explanation `$(basename "$file" .mp3)`:

With `$(basename "$file")` command I tried to get only filename with extension and with `$(basename "$file" .mp3)` I removed its extension too.

```
$ for file in ~/Main_dir/*.mp3; do echo $(basename "$file" .mp3);done
039 - Del Nevesht - noraei
Eluveitie - Meet The Enemy
```

---

```
$ for file in ~/Main_dir/*.mp3; do echo $(basename "$file");done
039 - Del Nevesht - noraei.mp3
Eluveitie - Meet The Enemy.mp3
```

#### Explanation `${file%.*}`:

I use this for getting the full filepath without its extension.

```
$ for file in ~/Main_dir/*.mp3; do echo "${file%.*}" ;done
/home/username/Main_dir/039 - Del Nevesht - noraei
/home/username/Main_dir/Eluveitie - Meet The Enemy
```

And with next line in script you will add a created .png label into your .mp3 files.

**Note:** I used `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`. You can use that if you have not `ffmpeg` package installed.

[see the demo convert](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9008539/)

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood from your question, I've written a bash script. Can you please check if it works correctly for you?

```
#!/bin/bash    
DIR="/path/to/directory"
FILES=`ls -1 "$DIR" | grep mp3$`
for file in "$FILES"
do
    FILENAME=`echo "$file" | cut -d "." -f1`
    convert -size 300x200   xc:lightblue  -font Bookman-DemiItalic  -pointsize 40  -fill blue  -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 '${FILENAME}'" ${FILENAME}.png
    ffmpeg -i ${FILENAME}.png -i $file ${FILENAME}.flv
done
```

Comment: This script will break with directory or file names that contain spaces or other special characters, which is _very_ common with MP3 files. At the very least you need to put double quotes `"` around `$DIR`, `$FILES`, `$file` so that the script handles spaces in names . Parsing the output of `ls -1` is not recommended, eg it will not work properly if any file names contain newlines `\n`; luckily, that's not so common. It's almost always much better to use `find` than to parse the output of `ls`, unless you can _guarantee_ that all file names are well-behaved.

Comment: But if you want to use `ls`, you should read its output into an array, eg `readarray -t names < <( ls -1 "$srcpath" )`

Comment: yes for filenames with space it does not work correctly.

Comment: @PM2Ring- Thank you for spotting that mistake. I have now put double quotes around the variables, as you suggested.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - Can you please test the amended script?

Comment: @MandarShinde: thank you. I'll test it and try to feedback.

Comment: No now it does not work with this error: `.png: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert all mp3 files in one folder you could use following code. Maybe do you have to correct folder names if you don´t want to have all files in one folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
SRCPATH="/home/user"
SRCEXT=".mp3"
SRCFILES="($SRCPATH/*$SRCEXT)"
cd $SRCPATH
for FILE in "${SRCFILES[@]}"; do
    SELECTION="$(basename $FILE $SRCEXT)"
    convert -size 300x200 xc:lightblue -font Bookman-DemiItalic -pointsize 40 -fill blue  -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 '$SELECTION'" $SELECTION.png
    ffmpeg -i $SELECTION.png -i $FILE $SELECTION.flv
done
```

Comment: I tested it but only one files with name `*.mp3).png` is created.